# How to submit form when any value selected from populated textbox using javascript or jQuery without clicking submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery

**search.php**

In this form, when we type something in textbox, matching words are fetched from `api_search.php` page and displayed as seen in attached screenshot.

```
<form role="form" id="frm_search" name="frm_search" method="POST" action="./api_search_p.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() 
    {
        $( "#txt_itemname" ).autocomplete({
        source: '../user/api_search.php'
        });
    });
    </script>
    <input type="text" id="txt_itemname" name="txt_itemname" class="form-control" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter something here">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning"><i class='fas fa-search'></i>&nbsp;</button></span>
</form>
```

**api_search.php**

Textbox on `search.php` is populated from API result data from this page.

```
-- API data are coming using curl in $result array --
$json = json_decode($result, true);

$arr_searchTerm = array(); 
if (is_array($json) && !empty($json))
{
    foreach ($json as $key1 => $level1)
    {
        if (is_array($level1) && !empty($level1))
        {
            foreach ($level1 as $key2 => $level2)
            {
                array_push($arr_searchTerm, $level2['TITLE']); 
            }
        }
    }
}
echo json_encode($arr_searchTerm);
```

Currently need to click submit button to submit the form. But I want to do so when any word from fetched result is selected / clicked then form should be submitted immediately without clicking submit button.

I tried `onselect="this.form.submit()"` & `onchange="this.form.submit()"` with textbox but form is not submitted on any of javascript events.

Please let me know how can I make this working as expected.

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: you can wrap your autocomplete options into some html tag, add a css class to it, add an event handler for the click event on that class that would just trigger the submit event for the form : $( "#frm_search" ).submit();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use select function in your code

```
 $( "#txt_itemname" ).autocomplete({
      source: '../user/api_search.php',
      select: function(e, ui){
                this.value = ui.item.value;
                this.form.submit();
              }
  });
```

Comment: Ty for your reply. Above code submits the form when any word selected. but it sends only entered word not selected word upon form submission. (For example I have typed `testo` and then I am selecting `TESTOPEL`. Then I am getting only `testo` in $_POST variables. I should get selected word `TESTOPEL`.

Comment: Hey @KRA1978 I've updated this code, please check it out.

Comment: Now, I am not able to fetch data from `api_search.php` page when typing something in search box on `search.php` page

Comment: Check the console for possible error. For your reference please check https://jsfiddle.net/4ab95o6j/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way. in this case, you can make your API call every time someone inserts something. This means every single letter will make a call

```
   document.querySelector("#txt_itemname").addEventListener('input',(e)=>{
        ...
    })
```

and additionally, if you do it as an API try to look at this too [http_responses with PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php)

Comment: Ty for your reply. Exactly where should I put this code? Please let me know.